# How to pass and assign keyup value to php variable on same php file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to pass the input value of this text field...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="No of persons" name="persons" id="persons" style="width:270px;">
```

and retrieve it in the same php file (assign it to $pers) in order to use that value for an if condition to display this part of a table inside a modal when a certain button is clicked.

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['persons']))
     {
          $pers=$_POST['persons'];
     }
     $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblrooms");
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $rno = $row['room_name'];
         $max = $row['max_occupancy'];
         $status = $row['status'];                              
         if($pers<=$max)
         {
    ?>
    <tr>
       <td style="font-size:13px;"><?php echo $rno; ?></td>
       <td style="font-size:13px;"><?php echo $max; ?></td>
       <td style="font-size:13px; display:none;"><?php echo $status; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
         }
     }
?>
```

Afterwards I have to retrieve some data inside the modal (I've already done that). So all I need is to assign the retrieved value from the text field in order to properly display the things inside the modal.

Script

```
<script>
      $('#persons').keyup(function()
      {
        var aj = $('#persons').val();

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'transaction_form.php',
          data: {persons: aj},
          success: function(response){
            $('$result').html(response);
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: What is `$` doing in `('$result')` in line of `$('$result').html(response);` ?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Just copied that code. I'm new to ajax and jquery. Sorry

Comment: It's a typo. Hehe. Pardon me

Comment: **1)** If `result` is class then use `$('.result').html(response);` **2)** If `result` is ID then use `$('#result').html(response);`

Comment: Please use mysqli or pdo . And then echo output

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. i'll be sure to check on mysqli and pdo. However my question is not with the sql.